# How do I keep my panel active in wxpython when plotting separate matlibplot figures

Tags: python, wxpython

Dear happy Python programmers,

I have just began to use wxpython and I think it is a quite cool tool. My problem is relatively simple. I am trying to plot graphs using matlibplot plot function from a wx.panel window (the button I call "Plot"). When I press "Plot" it should open a new window and make plot inside. It does the right thing, but my original panel is suddenly **inactive** and I can not press or see any buttons. However, when I close the matlibplot window my panel becomes active again and I can make another graph, but this is not the way I want. I want to **keep** all the previous graph windows open and close them only if I want it to.

The code below seems long, but it is very simple: You can either plot a polynomial function or exp function. The graph is in matlibplot Python style. You can try to run it and see for yourself what I mean with inactive window.

Does anybody know how I can keep the main panel active at all times and just keep plotting graphs?

Cheers happy people :-)

```
import wx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

class ExamplePanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        # the combobox Control
        self.mytext = wx.StaticText(self, label="", pos=(20,50))
        self.mytext.SetForegroundColour(wx.BLUE)
        self.funcs = ["y=2x^2+3","y=exp(2x+3)"]
        self.sampleList = ['polynomial', 'exponential']
        self.lblhear = wx.StaticText(self, label="Function", pos=(20,20))
        self.edithear = wx.ComboBox(self, pos=(100, 20), size=(95, -1), choices=self.sampleList, style=wx.CB_DROPDOWN)
        self.edithear.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.EvtComboBox)

        # A button
        self.button1 = wx.Button(self, label="Plot", pos=(20,80))
        self.button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick1)

    def EvtComboBox(self, event): 
        self.data = np.linspace(0,10,100)
        if event.GetString() == self.sampleList[0]:
            self.mytext.SetLabel(self.funcs[0])
            self.yfun=2*self.data**2+3
        elif event.GetString() == self.sampleList[1]:
            self.mytext.SetLabel(self.funcs[1])
            self.yfun=np.exp(2*self.data+3)
        else: 
            return()
        return(self.yfun)

    def OnClick1(self, event):
        plt.figure(1, figsize=(7,5))
        plt.plot(self.data, self.yfun, 'b-')
        plt.tick_params(axis="both", labelsize=15)
        plt.xlabel(r'$x$', fontsize=15)
        plt.ylabel(r'$y$', fontsize=15)
        plt.show()

app = wx.App(redirect=True)
frame = wx.Frame(None, title="A Simple Plotter", pos=(0, 45), size=(280,120))
ExamplePanel(frame)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your matplotlib is probably using a GUI backend other than wxPython, so whatever it is using will have its own equivallent to the MainLoop() call.  That means that control does not return to the wx MainLoop until the plot window is closed, so none of the wx event handlers can be called.

To resolve this you can tell matplotlib to use its "wxagg" backend instead of whatever it is defaulting to.  Something like this:

```
import wx
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('wxagg')
```

Comment: Thanks Robin :-) It seems that I have some problems loading the module backend_wxagg. Do you know how I can install it easily? I am using Fedora latest stable version.

Comment: I have tried several methods to include the missing package, for instance `sudo pip install wxagg` or `sudo pip install backend_wxagg` but the terminal says _No dsitribution at all found for wxagg_.

Comment: I have managed to get module backend_wxagg to run, I did by uninstalling matplotlib and installing it again, such as `sudo pip uninstall matplotlib` and `sudo pip install matplotlib`. My main window is now active, BUT I can not plot two graphs or more, the code only runs once and it stops. I need to cancle the graph in order to plot again. Is there a solution to this problem?